# Angular js load router again after the application starts

Tags: angularjs

My requirement is to decouple router and load it dynamically. So i formed the metadata in the format :

```
var routetable = {
    "records": [        
        {
            'Type': 'CustomView',
            "KeyName": "nav/downloads",
            "PageUrls": 'Templates/my-downloads.html',
        },
        {
            'Type': 'ListView',
            "KeyList": [ "779", "153", "819"],
            "RouteName" : "listview-group",
            "PageUrls": "Templates/ListView.html"
        }       
    ]
};


And i am forming the router using following code :

var iLoop = 0, currentRoute;
                for (iLoop = 0; iLoop < rtable.records.length; iLoop++) {
                    currentRoute = rtable.records[iLoop];
                    if (currentRoute.Type == "CustomView") {
                        var routeName = "/" + currentRoute.KeyName;
                        $routeSegmentProvider.when(routeName, 'nav.' + currentRoute.KeyName)

                        $routeSegmentProvider.within().segment(currentRoute.KeyName, {
                            templateUrl: currentRoute.PageUrls,
                            // controller: 'CookingAndBlastController',
                            resolve: {
                                data: function ($timeout) {
                                    return $timeout(function () { return 'SLOW DATA CONTENT'; }, 300);
                                }
                            },
                            untilResolved: {
                                templateUrl: 'Templates/loading.html'
                            }

                        })
                    }

                    else if (currentRoute.Type == "ListView") {
                        for (var j = 0; j < currentRoute.KeyList.length ; j++) {
                            var routeName = "/" + currentRoute.KeyList[j];
                            $routeSegmentProvider.when(routeName, 'nav.' + currentRoute.RouteName)
                        }

                        $routeSegmentProvider.within().segment(currentRoute.RouteName, {
                            templateUrl: currentRoute.PageUrls,
                            // controller: 'CookingAndBlastController',
                            resolve: {
                                data: function ($timeout) {
                                    return $timeout(function () { return 'SLOW DATA CONTENT'; }, 300);
                                }
                            },
                            untilResolved: {
                                templateUrl: 'Templates/loading.html'
                            }

                        })
                    }
                }

It works fine when "routetable" metadata is available within app.js .
```

But my requirement is to get this "routetable" metadata on application start , i will download routing path from server for different pages and reload the router.

```
I want to know how to reload router, once the application is started  ?
```

Comment: Take care when writing code and text, they should be well separated. In your post above they are amalgamated and it makes the question hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Since the *$http* service is not available in the *config* phase of your app (when you configure your router) you cannot request the routing array from the server API at that time.

There are several workarounds for this but the simplest option is to include a js file from the server (it may be dynamically generated, of course). It will contain your routing data and whatever else you may need.

Your *js* file may look like this (or like in your code):

```
angular.module('shared')
.constant('ROUTETABLE', "records": [        
    {
        'Type': 'CustomView',
        "KeyName": "nav/downloads",
        "PageUrls": 'Templates/my-downloads.html',
    },
    {
        'Type': 'ListView',
        "KeyList": [ "779", "153", "819"],
        "RouteName" : "listview-group",
        "PageUrls": "Templates/ListView.html"
    }       
]

);
```

then you will import the js file in *index.html*:

```
<script src="https://your-server/path/dynamic-routes.js"></script>
```

and then you can use your routing code like you did so far.

If you use UI Router with states, you can create your dynamic routes like this:

```
ROUTETABLE.records.forEach(function(myRoute) {
    $stateProvider.state('main.state' + myRoute['Type'], {
        url: '/' + 'some-dynamic-path',
        params: {
            KeyName: {
                value: myRoute['KeyName']
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            data: function ($timeout) {
                return $timeout(function () { return 'SLOW DATA CONTENT'; }, 300);
                }
           },
        views: {
            'main.content@': {
                templateUrl: myRoute['PageUrls'],
                controller: 'SomeCtrl'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

*The code above isn't tested (though it should work) but you get my drift.*

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: Please don't answer to this question (already flagged), let him edit/beautify first, we are respectful developers!

Comment: I made a comment on this aspect and I was about to beautify the question myself but I think you are right, he should learn how to write readable text/code.